# Render html in yajra datatables using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, yajra-datatable

I am facing a problem displaying image in data table. The below code is displaying the whole html(HTML is not getting rendered) in side the column. It used to work with laravel 5.3 and below. How to get it working with *laravel 5.4*. Thanks.

```
        $data = Member::query()
        ->get();
        return Datatables::of($data)
        ->addColumn('picture', function ($data) {
            return '<img src=" '.$data->picture.' "/>';
        })
        ->make(true);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay I found the solution you just need to add `->rawColumns()` before `->make(true)`

```
->rawColumns(['picture', 'confirmed'])
```

while returning. Cheers!!

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a yajra dataTable related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208578/laravel-yajra-datatable-cannot-retrieve-the-search-parameter-from-ajax-call-in ?

Answer (score 1):

you have to define the full src of image in img tag

```
Like this
<img style="width: 140px;" src="/images/your-folder-name/'.$data->pictur.'">
```

Comment: yea, I know that but it is displaying the raw html. If the path is incorrect it should show the broken image. the image tag u posted is totally wrong. Sorry but this is not the solution to my problem

Comment: what you exactly want ?

Comment: HTML is not getting rendered in laravel 5.4. However in 5.3 and below it used to work like this.